# From general Hamiltonian to Ising Hamiltonian

Tags: qiskit, vqe, d-wave, chemistry

I would like to convert my qubit hamiltonian fom the HeH+ system that I have obtained using Qiskit to an Ising or QUBO model. I have seen multiples examples from QUBO to Qubit Hamiltonian but on the other direction no. Does anyone know how I can do it? Attached my Qubit Hamiltonian.
[image: Qubit Hamiltonian]

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it would be to use a transformation, such as [this one](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jpcb.7b10371):

\begin{align}
X_i &= \frac{1 - Z_{i,j}Z_{i,k}}{2}\textrm{sgn}(j)\textrm{sgn}(k)\tag{1}\\
Y_i &= \textrm{i}\frac{Z_{i,k}-Z_{i,j}}{2}\textrm{sgn}(j)\textrm{sgn}(k)\tag{2}\\
Z_i &= \frac{Z_{i,j}+Z_{i,k}}{2}\textrm{sgn}(j)\textrm{sgn}(k)\tag{3}\\
I_i &= \frac{1 + Z_{i,j}Z_{i,k}}{2}\textrm{sgn}(j)\textrm{sgn}(k)\tag{4}.\\
\end{align}

Then all of your $X$ and $Y$ operators will be $Z$ operators. In other words, you've transformed a general XYZ model into an Ising model with the help of auxiliary qubits with labels such as $(i,j)$ and $(i,k)$.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your quick reply! I understand the transformation but I am unsure on how to set sgn(j) and sgn(k). If from my original hamiltonian I don't have those qubits, how do I know the values of sgn(j) or sgn(k)? Thank you in advance!!!